# Binary data in dynamodb

Tags: binary, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am new to dynamo db binary data. I have a hash key + range key(both are byte[]). Now I am trying to get a list of items by querying on range key(ex: le, ge or between). I am able to do put and get operations fine.

However I am getting errors while doing this. My question is can dynamodb do this comparison? I am passing a byte[]. Can dynamodb check if existing rangekey(byte[]) is lesser or greater than this?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: The BETWEEN condition was provided a range where the lower bound is greater than the upper bound -> However, I checked the input before conversion to byte array confirms from < to

Answer (score 0):

Yes, DynamoDB does support the byte array type well, and also allows comparison between them in conditions, done lexicographically, so what you want to do should and does work.

You didn't say which "errors" you are getting. You should be aware that DynamoDB treats the bytes of the byte arrays as *unsigned* bytes. For example, the byte 128 comes after byte 127. I don't know which language you are using to test this, but some languages have signed bytes - meaning that the byte 128 is treated as "-1" and will come before, not after, byte 127 in the sort order. DynamoDB doesn't do that, because it uses unsigned bytes.

Comment: Thank you for the inputs.I am using java byte[]. I checked the data and it is coming in as signed(there are negative values in byte[]). It might be the reason for dynamodb not being able to do the comparison.

Comment: The error I am getting SOMETIMES while try ing to use between operator on range key(byte[]) is The BETWEEN condition was provided a range where the lower bound is greater than the upper bound